# Transformation Working Differently in Path and Rectangle

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am drawing a rectangle and a Path using GDI+ and C++ on a custom control.
Here is my Code...

```
Gdiplus::RectF myRectF(50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
Gdiplus::Matrix myMatrix(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
Gdiplus::Graphics gdiGraphics(hDC); // hdC is my Device Context

Gdiplus::Pen* myPen = new Gdiplus::Pen(Gdiplus::Color::White);
myPen->SetWidth(2);

gdiGraphics.TranslateTransform(100.0f, 100.0f, Gdiplus::MatrixOrderAppend);
gdiGraphics.SetTransform(&myMatrix);
gdiGraphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectF);

Gdiplus::GraphicsPath *myPath = new Gdiplus::GraphicsPath();
myPath->AddRectangle(myRectF);
myPath->Transform(&myMatrix);
gdiGraphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), myPath);
```

But the Rectangle is drawn at some DIFFERENT place than Path.

if I don't do the transformation part from both (Rectangle and Path), then these two are drawn at the same cordinates, so I was just wondering whether these two transformations are working differently or I am using some wrong API.

and the rectangle drawn in the Path is the correct one where it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rectangle and the Path are drawn in different places because you apply the transformation twice to the path. First when you set it as the Graphics Object world transformation:

```
gdiGraphics.SetTransform(&myMatrix);
```

and then you also transform the path:

```
myPath->Transform(&myMatrix);
```

When the objects are drawn the Rectangle is affected only by the Graphics object's translation but the Path is affected both by the Graphics object's translation and its own translation.

If you want to draw both shapes in the same place it is enough to apply the translation to the Graphics object.

Also, when you set the Graphics Object's transformation matrix with SetTransform() you override the previous TranslateTransform() operation.